# Contabilizar personas según sus años de Servicio Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una tabla **TRABAJADOR** con un campo **F_INGRESO** tipo **DATE**.

Mi problema surge a que los registros del campo **F_INGRESO** al ser tipo date, no tengo el **año** directamente. Por ejemplo: "X" trabajador ingresó hace **7** años. Así que, tengo que sacar ese año por su fecha de ingreso y compararla con la fecha actual del **sistema** y saber la antiguedad que tiene el trabajdor.

Contruí una **función** para obtener el año entre dos fechas, una sería la fecha de ingreso del trabajador y otra la fecha actual, para comparar hace cuántos años ingresó.

```
CREATE TABLE TRABAJADOR( 
             COD_TRA VARCHAR2(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
             AP_TRA VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
             AM_TRA VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
             NOM_TRA VARCHAR2(15) NULL,
             FECHA_NA DATE NULL,
             SUELDO NUMERIC(8,2) NULL,
             GENERO_TRA VARCHAR2(1) NULL,
             AREA_TRA VARCHAR2(30) NULL;
             F_INGRESO DATE NULL);

INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00001','DE LA MADRID','GUTIERREZ' , 'MARICIELO', '01/11/1980',980,'F','CONTABILIDAD','10/12/2020');
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00002','HURTADO','CORONEL', 'NILDA', '10/10/1976',980.50,'F','CONTABILIDAD','05/11/2017');
INSERT INTO TRABAJADOR VALUES ('00003','PAREDES','MARTINEZ','EDITH', '10/10/1976',1500.50,'F','SISTEMAS','15/04/2021');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ANIOS_DIF
    (fecha1 DATE, fecha2 DATE) RETURN NUMBER AS v_anios_dif NUMBER(6); BEGIN v_anios_dif := ABS(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(fecha2,fecha1)/ 12)); RETURN v_anios_dif; END ANIOS_DIF;
```

Al obtener el año, ahora quiero contar los trabajadores por años de servicio.

**Ejemplo** de Salida de Datos:

Entre hace 1-4 años: 15 Trabajadores ==> CONTINUAR LABORANDO

Entre hace 5-6 años: 8 Trabajadores ==> PENDIENTE DE JUBILACIÓN

Entre hace 7 a más años: 9 Trabajadores ==> DESPEDIDOS.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Kasparov, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select T.Estado, count(*) as Total
from
(
 select 
  case 
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) >= 1 and 
        trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) <= 4
      then 'CONTINUAR LABORANDO'
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) >= 5 and 
        trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) <= 6
      then 'PENDIENTE DE JUBILACIÓN' 
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) > 7 
      then 'DESPEDIDOS' 
  end as Estado 
 from trabajador
) T
group by T.Estado
```

Aquí se hace una **subconsulta**:

```
select 
  case 
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) >= 1 and 
        trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) <= 4
      then 'CONTINUAR LABORANDO'
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) >= 5 and 
        trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) <= 6
      then 'PENDIENTE DE JUBILACIÓN' 
   when trunc(months_between (CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12) > 7 
      then 'DESPEDIDOS' 
  end as Estado 
from trabajador
```

Donde se utiliza la **sentencia Case** para establecer los rangos de edades. Para hacer el cálculo de estos rangos de edades se usa la instrucción:

```
trunc(months_between(CURRENT_DATE, F_INGRESO) / 12)
```

Donde se utiliza a la **función months_between** para calcular los meses que hay entre dos fechas (En **Oracle** hasta donde tengo entendido no hay una forma directa de obtener los años entre dos fechas), posteriormente se **divide entre 12**, de esta forma obtenemos los años correspondientes entre las dos fechas y aplicando la **función trunc** pues obtenemos la **parte entera de esta división**, ya que la división podría dar como resultado un número con comas, y en este caso específico solo nos interesa la parte entera del número. Según los rangos específicos que se analizan en la **instrucción Case** se establecerán los valores **"CONTINUAR LABORANDO"**, **"PENDIENTE DE JUBILACIÓN"** y **"DESPEDIDOS"**. A la **instrucción Case** se le da como **alias el nombre de Estado**. Para obtener la fecha actual se utiliza la **función CURRENT_DATE**.

A esta **subconsulta** le aplicamos entonces una **consulta general** la cual utilizando la **cláusula group by** por el **campo Estado** y la **función de agregación count** en la **cláusula select** obtendremos por cada rango de edad los totales correspondientes.